# homemade wine problem

Tags: fermentation, wine, airlock, problems

My question is in my primary fermenter. If the airlock is not bubbling does that mean its not fermenting. I have two on the go one is bubbling and the other one is. What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to be sure if it is fermenting is to check the gravity.  If the airlock is not bubbling it could just mean the seal on the bucket lid (or stopper) is not sealed air-tight.  It may also need more time before it kicks up.  The only time I fermented wine, it was a much less active-looking fermentation than beer.  I'd say wait a day or two, then take a gravity reading.  If it hasn't dropped, pitch more yeast.

Answer (score 1):

I agree about the bucket seal and a gravity reading, but if you have one active fermentation and one inactive, I would decant the active wine into a secondary, and siphon the other onto the yeast cake in the active primary.  The fermentation would pick up faster than repitching since the yeast is fully active and dispersed in an identical solution.  Wine yeasts are strong fermenters so I wouldn't be concerned about thinning the pitching rate.